# Indexing website/url in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `website` field of a document indexed in elastic search. Example value: http://example.com . The problem is that when I search for `example`, the document is not included. How to map correctly the website/url field?

I created the index below:

```
{
  "settings":{
    "index":{
        "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
            "analyzer_html":{
                  "type":"custom",
                  "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter":"standard",
                "char_filter": "html_strip"
            }
        }
        }
    }
  },
  "mapping":{
    "blogshops": {
        "properties": {
            "category": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "reviews": {
                "properties": {
                    "user": {
                        "properties": {
                            "_id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

I guess you are using `standard` analyzer, which splits `http://example.dom` into two tokens - `http` and `example.com`. You can take a look `http://localhost:9200/_analyze?text=http://example.com&analyzer=standard`.

If you want to split `url`, you need to use different [analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/) or specify our own [custom analyzer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html).

You can take a look how would be `url` indexed with [simple analyzer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) - `http://localhost:9200/_analyze?text=http://example.com&analyzer=simple`. As you can see, now is `url` indexed as three tokens `['http', 'example', 'com']`. If you don't want to index tokens like `['http', 'www']` etc, you can specify your analyzer with [lowercase tokenizer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenizer.html) (this is the one used in simple analyzer) and [stop filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html). For example something like this:

```
# Delete index
#
curl -s -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/url-test/' ; echo
 
# Create index with mapping and custom index
#
curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/url-test/' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer" : "lowercase_with_stopwords"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 0
    },
    "analysis": {
      "filter" : {
        "stopwords_filter" : {
          "type" : "stop",
          "stopwords" : ["http", "https", "ftp", "www"]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase_with_stopwords": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "lowercase",
          "filter": [ "stopwords_filter" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}' ; echo

curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/url-test/_analyze?text=http://example.com&analyzer=lowercase_with_stopwords&pretty'

# Index document
#
curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/url-test/document/1?pretty=true' -d '{
  "content" : "Small content with URL http://example.com."
}'

# Refresh index
#
curl -s -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/url-test/_refresh'

# Try to search document
#
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/url-test/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "content:example"
    }
  }
}'
```

NOTE: If you don't like to use stopwords here is interesting article [stop stopping stop words: a look at common terms query](http://www.elastic.co/blog/stop-stopping-stop-words-a-look-at-common-terms-query/)

Comment: thanks @vhyza. I updated the question w/ how I created the index. I have a nested property and want to strip html.

Comment: You are welcome. Nested properties should be fine. You can add `char_filter` in `lowercase_with_stopwords ` to strip html if you want.