# Include all non-numeric web sites to elastic query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query that works as expected. The only problem is that I want to use regular expression so that all amazonaws.com sites should be included.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "sourceIPAddress": "1.179.67.49"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "sourceIPAddress": "1.69.88.195"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "sourceIPAddress": "config.amazonaws.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "sourceIPAddress": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

How do I add this query to the one mentioned above?

```
{  "query": {    "regexp": {      "sourceIPAddress": {        "value": "[a-zA-Z].+"      }    }  }}
```

The regular expression will include all sites (i.e. non-numeric) to the query. How do I mention *.amazonaws.com?

Comment: What is your mappings? I suggest to create a custom analyzer (using a reverse token with edgegram token and then using prefix to match the suffix created by this analyzer).

Comment: mapping is here ... https://testme162.s3.amazonaws.com/crawler_mapping.txt

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34986008/4604579 (hint: don't use regexp but a custom analyzer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Val is correct -- it'd be best to reindex using [custom analyzers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18980048/8160318). It will cost you some time and effort to reindex but your queries will work faster than the below solution which uses a wildcard query -- which is expensive because it uses a leading `*`. Note that I'm using `.keyword` because it's not analyzed and that you've gotta escape dots, just like in a regex.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "sourceIPAddress": "1.179.67.49"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "sourceIPAddress": "1.69.88.195"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "sourceIPAddress.keyword": {
             "value": "*\\.amazonaws\\.com*"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Try it and see if the performance stays reasonable. If not, you'll have to reindex.