# parse ingest http logs api_name to elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have http log with field url:"/api/api_name/api_id"

example1 url: /api/apiX/0121313123

example2 url: /api/apiY/012132/optionX/1000

What is the best practice to extract from the url and ingest in elasticsearch only the "/api/api_name" and remove the id so it is suitable to visualize later in kibana distribution per api_name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977834/indexing-website-url-in-elastic-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best practice, but what works for us is that we index URL as a separate field only for the API:

```json
DELETE urls

PUT /urls
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "api_extractor_char_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "/?api/([^/]+)/?.*",
          "replacement": "api/$1"
        }
      },
      "normalizer": {
        "api_extractor": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "api_extractor_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "url": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "api": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "api_extractor"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /urls/_doc
{"url":"/api/apiX/0121313123"}
POST /urls/_doc
{"url":"/api/apiY/012132/optionX/1000"}

GET /urls/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "url.api": {
        "value": "/api/apiY"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way we keep the original URL and with the `.api` field index only what you're asking for. This field can be used for exact searches and aggregations. It will work just fine for your use case.

Other possible ways:

- Use ingestion pipelines to change document source and extract URL
- Ingest both URL and API names separately from your application/logs collector